# Appending table values from a webpage to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

I want to get the table from webpage

```
import os
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.page_load_strategy = 'eager'
options.add_argument("--headless");
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)   
driver.get("https://munafasutra.com/nse/dividends")
file_object = open('divident.csv', 'a')
```

output table

[image]

How to get the first table and their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look at the HTML path and locate the WebElement that is gathering that first table (Clicking "Inspect" when you click right-button of the mouse can do the work).

You can save that webelement using the following line of code:

```
first_table = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'co']//table[1]") # The [1] is not really necessary as when using **find_element_by_xpath** will only look for the first element.
```

Then, if you look at how data is organized inside that table, you can observe each row is gathered by a **tr** WebElement. Therefore, if you wish to write it in a csv file, I would suggest to write row by row with the following code:

```
rows = first_table.find_elements_by_xpath("./tbody/tr") 
for row in rows:
    entries_of_the_row = row.find_elements_by_xpath("./td") 
    row_to_csv = []
    for entry in entries_of_the_row:
        row_to_csv.append(entry.text)
    file_object.write(f"{row_to_csv[0]}, {row_to_csv[1]}, {row_to_csv[2]}, {row_to_csv[3]}, {row_to_csv[4]}\n")   
file_object.close()
```

Comment: one "/" was missing to find the table. It is fixed now.

Comment: one bracket is also missing but did resolve the issue. Thank you @JorgeHB

Answer (score 1):

You can use below XPATH to retrieve the first table value :

```
//h3[text()=' Earlier dividends announced by companies ']/preceding-sibling::table/descendant::td
```

Something like this :

```
driver.get("https://munafasutra.com/nse/dividends")
first_table = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h3[text()=' Earlier dividends announced by companies ']/preceding-sibling::table/descendant::td")
for first in first_table: 
   print(first.text)
```

Comment: values are not coming in comma-separated for each row

Answer (score 1):

You can use **BeautifulSoup** to get the table data. Selenium is not required if you just want to extract web page data.

You need to import below packages :

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

You can Extract HTML of the table using below code (soup variable will contain the HTML code of the entire page):

```
url_munafasutra = "https://munafasutra.com/nse/dividends"
html_munafasutra = urlopen(url_munafasutra)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_munafasutra, 'html')
```

Below is the code to extract HTML for the 1st table (here **table is the tag** value and in **[] contains the index** of the table we want to extract data of):

```
first_table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
```

You can also add attributes to distinctly identify the table along with tag name.

Below is the code to extract all the rows in the selected table :

```
all_rows = first_table.findAll("tr")
```

Use the below code to write the data in csv file :

```
with open("C:\\Users\\abhay\\.spyder-py3\\table_extract.csv", "wt+", newline="") as f:
    table_to_csv = csv.writer(f)
    for row in all_rows:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.findAll(["td", "th"]):
            row_data.append(cell.get_text())
        table_to_csv.writerow(row_data)
```

Below is the complete code to extract 1st table data to csv :

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_munafasutra = "https://munafasutra.com/nse/dividends" 
html_munafasutra = urlopen(url_munafasutra)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_munafasutra, 'html')

first_table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
all_rows = first_table.findAll("tr")

with open("C:\\Users\\abhay\\.spyder-py3\\table_extract.csv", "wt+", newline="") as f:
    table_to_csv = csv.writer(f)
    for row in all_rows:
        row_data = []
        for cell in row.findAll(["td", "th"]):
            row_data.append(cell.get_text())
        table_to_csv.writerow(row_data)
```